# GCM Curl Script Invalid Registration

Tags: php, android, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement a gcm through a curl script. When i preview the page what i get is invalid registration whilst i've provide my API key. in the script i downloaded,its having a line `"registration ids"` which is already having some values in there. Now my question is where do i get to get my registration id to input into the script. i'm kinda confused

```
//request url
$url    = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

//your api key
$apiKey = 'AIzaSyAHb_Mh27PNnNkwj------------tkqKjc';

//registration ids
$registrationIDs = array('APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...');

//payload data
$data   = array('score' => '1-0', 'scorer' => 'Ronaldo', 'time' => '44');

$fields = array('registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
                'data' => $data);

//http header
$headers = array('Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                 'Content-Type: application/json');

//curl connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: is your server's IP allowed to use the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation for the [Downstream message error response codes](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes).

> Invalid Registration Token 200 + error:InvalidRegistration
>
> Check the format of the registration token you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with GCM. Do not truncate or add additional characters.

Answer (score 0):

`registration_id` is generated on the client side (Android/IOS app), not the server side. Check out [GCM guides](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).